# Looking at the value of a TVar in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, stm, tvar

Working through [Simon Peyton Jones](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/beautiful-concurrency/3-software-transactional-memory) concurrency example, I have the following code:

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar

deposit account amount = do
    bal <- readTVar account
    writeTVar account (bal+amount)
```

I am trying to test this in GHCi REPL

```
*Main> checking <- atomically $ newTVar 100
*Main> atomically $ deposit checking 10
```

How do I verify my checking balance is $110?

I have tried

```
*Main> checking
*Main> readTVar checking
*Main> balance <- readTVar checking
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`atomically $ readTVar checking` does what you want. The GHCi REPL automatically executes any IO action that you give it.

Comment: For this simple case, there's also `readTVarIO`, which is equivalent to `atomically . readTVar` but more efficient.